# Triggering mouse events on element under cursor while dragging another element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have a file tree with draggable folders and files within it, using custom code (with Backbone, which is irrelevant). When I drag an item, I "affix" a dragging element to the mouse cursor to show the item has been picked up.

Whilst I'm dragging the item around, however, I want to be able to trigger mouse events on other files and folders in the tree (in my case `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. The issue here is that the element under the cursor is the one being dragged, meaning no other mouse events are triggered.

How can I "see through" the element I'm dragging with the cursor so mouse events are still triggered on the rest of the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really quite neat solution is to use pseudo elements in one's CSS. Other solutions suggest keeping a cache of element dimensions and do coordinate matching, however this is messy and error prone; what if the element moves? It's also rather slow.

My solution is to give each element that you want to trigger mouse events on (whilst dragging another element) an `:after` property with the dimensions of the element.

[Here is a JSBin demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ohanet/3/edit).

#### (Basic) CSS

```
.dragging {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.drop-target {
    position: relative;
}

.drop-target:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The neat bit is to set the `z-index` of the `:after` to one *higher* than the element being dragged by the cursor. This means that mouse events will be triggered on the underlying element because the mouse is technically hovering over the (transparent) pseudo element *on top of* the element being dragged.

The dragged element will then go under the `:after` but above the actual element meaning both display and behaviour remain correct.